# Correct format structure creating variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it ok to create `vars` with spaces and forward slashes?

Like so:

```
var PICKUPS / TRUCKS = {};
```

Comment: If you were to try that you'd find out immediately that the answer is "no".

Comment: Probably not since '/' is also the divide operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, variable names **cannot have spaces**, but some special characters *are* allowed.

To reference the list of valid characters you can **[refer to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9337047/3960969)**.

**In your case, this is invalid in Javascript:**

```
// INVALID!
var PICKUPS / TRUCKS = {};
```

First, the `/` operator is the `divide operator`, so the Javascript interpreter will look at this like a Mathematical operation, trying to "divide PICKUPS with TRUCKS", which will cause an error, especially after the `var` keyword, it won't know how to make sense of that (for example, first it will see that you are trying to create a variable, and then it will see that instead of creating a variable, you are trying to do some math, which will confuse the javascript interpreter).

**But you can do something like this:**

```
// Valid Javascript; No spaces or illegal characters
var pickups_trucks = {};
```

**Also, if the names are embedded in javascript objects**, you can name objects using string identifiers, where anything legal in a string can work:

```
var Automobiles = {
    "Trucks & Pickups": [],
    "Three Wheelers": []
};

console.log(Automobiles["Trucks & Pickups"]);
```

**Hope this helps!**

Answer (score 2):

No, this is **NOT VALID** variable name in javascript. It cannot have spaces or forward slash in it.

Here https://mothereff.in/js-variables you can test if your variable name is valid or not

Answer (score 1):

This is invalid javascript.

I recommend you declare variables separately like such:

```
var PICKUPS = 0,
    TRUCKS = {};
```

I recommend you use a tool like [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) or [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/) to verify you code.

Answer (score 0):

In any programming language its not a good idea to use spaces or slashes in your variable names.  There are several ways to write vars using underscores, camel case or snake case are just a few.